# Why am I getting this native_pdf_renderer error when running flutter Android App?

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, dart

I did an upgrade from flutter 2 to 3, when I try to run the app in Android I get this error:

```
* What went wrong:
e: C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\native_pdf_renderer-4.0.1\android\src\main\kotlin\io\scer\native_pdf_ren
derer\NativePdfRendererPlugin.kt: (124, 29): Type mismatch: inferred type is String? but String was expected
e: C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\native_pdf_renderer-4.0.1\android\src\main\kotlin\io\scer\native_pdf_ren
derer\NativePdfRendererPlugin.kt: (138, 25): Type mismatch: inferred type is String? but String was expected

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':native_pdf_renderer:compileDebugKotlin'.
> Compilation error. See log for more details

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with -
-scan to get full insights.
```

Some of the things I tried:

1. Flutter clean
2. gradlew clean
3. pub upgrade
4. Changed to compileSdkVersion 33 in build.gradle
5. Added ? in String to `val id = call.arguments<String>()` since the error points to that location
6. Changed to targetSdkVersion 33 in build.gradle

The error points out to these 2 functions in NativePdfRendererPlugin.kt:

```
private fun closeDocumentHandler(call: MethodCall, result: Result) {
    try {
        val id = call.arguments<String>()
        documents.close(id) // <----
        result.success(null)
    } catch (e: NullPointerException) {
        result.error("PDF_RENDER", "Need call arguments: id!", null)
    } catch (e: RepositoryItemNotFoundException) {
        result.error("PDF_RENDER", "Document not exist in documents repository", null)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        result.error("PDF_RENDER", "Unknown error", null)
    }
}

private fun closePageHandler(call: MethodCall, result: Result) {
    try {
        val id = call.arguments<String>()
        pages.close(id)  // <----
        result.success(null)
    } catch (e: NullPointerException) {
        result.error("PDF_RENDER", "Need call arguments: id!", null)
    } catch (e: RepositoryItemNotFoundException) {
        result.error("PDF_RENDER", "Page not exist in pages repository", null)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        result.error("PDF_RENDER", "Unknown error", null)
    }
}
```

flutter doctor:

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.0.5, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19044.1889], locale en-US)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.0.0)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.0.5)
[√] Android Studio (version 2021.1)
[√] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
[√] VS Code (version 1.66.0)
[√] Connected device (5 available)
[√] HTTP Host Availability
```

Comment: The problem has been solved, the dependency thumbnailer  was using an old version (version 4) of native_pdf_renderer, we find out we were not using that package and proceed to deleted, the solution could be found here:   https://github.com/ScerIO/packages.flutter/issues/298#issuecomment-1148519805